# Screen Brightness not Changing on Dell XPS 7590

Tags: 18.04, dell, brightness, xps

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS a new [Dell XPS 7590](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/new-xps-15-7590/spd/xps-15-7590-laptop) laptop with OLED display, the brightness is stuck at the highest point (the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> commands show that the brightness is being changed, but no brightness change occurs).

I have tried many suggestions from the web, but all failed; e.g., changing the `acpi_backlight` parameter values in `/etc/default/grub`, creating an `xbacklightmon` file, or installing brightness controller.

Is there any way that the brightness could be changed?

Comment: Same on Mint 19.2 Cinnamon

Comment: SAme on 19.10 in any prime-select mode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend using the ICC Brightness tool, which worked well for my Dell 7590 with OLED screen. It requires compiling and installing a small utility, but it works well.

Full instructions can be found at https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness but here is a summary.

```
$ sudo apt install git liblcms2-dev
$ mkdir ~/git
$ cd ~/git
$ git clone https://github.com/udifuchs/icc-brightness
$ cd icc-brightness
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

After a reboot your brightness keys should now work. Be careful not to use this in conjuction with the xrandr solutions as they don't play nicely together.

Comment: cheers !! This really did the trick... Just for the record, last command requires `sudo`

Comment: Yes, good point. I've updated my answer. Thank you @dgoosens.

Comment: great... now I just need to figure out how to setup dual screen (other screen is not 4K) as this does not seem to work very well with the Nvidia drivers (works, but ugly with Nouveau drivers)

Comment: It works for me on a Dell XPS 15 7590 w/ OLED screen, at least, to some extent. System keys don't work, but I can set the brightness on the command line. `icc-brightness 82000 120000`

Comment: Hi @MarioOlivioFlores. It may work after a reboot, as there's an autostart element which does the hook-up to the keys. I have the same model laptop and it's working for me.

Comment: @David I appreciate the response! I've been working with it through multiple reboots - sadly no luck. :/  I don't think it is worth debugging. I wrote a little script to make it easy to use.

Answer (score 6):

Enter `xrandr` and check the output. In my case it was *eDP-1*. 
To test if it is the right one, enter `xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.6` (intel driver). If yes, the brightness should have changed.

I found it at [How to install Ubuntu on a Dell XPS 15 2019](https://github.com/TillmannBerg/Ubuntu-Dell-XPS-15-2019).

Comment: Tried this, however, screen brightness did not change even after changing eDP-1 to XWAYLAND0 (my graphics card). Setting up the script seems to have worked, but the xrandr command doesn't.

Comment: On my system the display wasn't `eDP-1` but instead `eDP-1-1` and so I used this command which both discovers the display and then changes the brightness : `xrandr --output $(xrandr --listmonitors | awk '$1 == "0:" {print $4}') --brightness 0.6`

Answer (score 0):

Followed this on a Dell XPS with Ubuntu 18.  Apparently OLED displays are treated different.  Command that worked for me was

`sudo xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --brightness 0.7`

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/xps-15-9570-with-Ubuntu-18-04-02-LTS-problem-with-hotkeys-F11/td-p/7287583